# Recorrer Filas Datatable jQuery y Deshabilitar botón

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Estoy creando una aplicación asp.net mvc que usa datatable de jquery para mostrar información.

Una de las columnas es un boton, y necesito recorrer todas las filas y deshabilitar ese boton cuando el campo de otra columna(status) contenga datos

[image: datatable]

Por ejemplo en esta fila necesito deshabilitar el botón ya que la columna Status posee datos. Solo tengo que mostrar el botón cuando la columna Status no posea datos.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#recargo').DataTable({



        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Datos/LoadData,
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [


            {

                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<a type="button" id="boton" class="btn btn-info" style="color:black" href="#"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> +</a >';
                }
            },

            { "data": "Pago", "name": "Pago", "autoWidth": true, render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2, '$') },
            { "data": "Monto", "name": "Monto", "autoWidth": true, render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2, '$') },
            { "data": "Status", "name": "Status", "autoWidth": true },


        ]
    });
});
```

Alguna idea de como hacerlo se que tendría que ir comparando fila por fila para ir habilitando o deshabilitando el boton.

Comment: Que te sale en consola cuando haces `console.log(row);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con Datatablejs puedes acceder a las otras propiedades del row cuando lo estás [renderizando la columna](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render).
Tu parámetro row de render es tu objeto completo, desde el puedes acceder al Status. De está forma podrás leerlo para deshabilitar el botón.

```
"render": function (data, type, row) {
                    let deshabilitado = "";
                    if(row.Status === ""){
                        deshabilitado  = "disabled"
                    }
                    return '<a type="button" id="boton" class="btn btn-info" style="color:black" href="#" '+deshabilitado+'><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> +</a >';
                }
```

Comment: Trato de implementarlo y no  funciona trato de agregarle hidden y tampoco funciona, inspeccionando el elemento veo que no agrega el atributo

Comment: Que versión de datatable usas?

Comment: Ya lo resolvi gracias lo que hice fue ocultar el boton por medio del id

Comment: if(row.Status != null){
                        $('#boton').hide();
                    }

Comment: haciendo pruebas este día la solución que me diste solo funciona al momento de cargar el datatable la primera vez pero si luego le estoy agregando mas info al datatable solo me funciona con la primera fila en las demas filas no hace las validaciones

Comment: Lo sé. Lo noté desde que vi tu código. Pero esto es un punto distinto a esta pregunta. Abre una nueva pregunta, puedes referenciar a esta para no perder el hilo.

Comment: ya hice la nueva pregunta, talve me podes ayudar a resolverla https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/289906/recorrer-filas-datatable-jquery-para-ocultar-boton